# Ionic Start ionic content from bottom

Tags: angularjs, css, scroll, ionic-framework

I am following slack app example behavior of comment ,I want to add comment inside

```
     <ion-content>




     <!-- start comments from bottom and and every entry from bottom to top scroll up and currently automatically there is <div> after content with style : transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1); which set it up at top by default-->
    </ion-content>
```

Please let me know the any material which help me to sort out.

Regards
Shivam

Comment: Please add what code you have tried.

Comment: <div style="clear:both;">
        <ol class="messages" >
          <li ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-bind-html="message.content">  </li>
        </ol>
      </div>